# Should an output be output reg if using it in an instantiated sub module?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to troubleshoot some code, which I might post later, but first I'm wondering if I need to change some of my module port definitions from simple outputs to output reg's? I know if I'm using an assign operation, it should simply be output; however, if I'm using multiple layers of instantiated modules, are the actual instantiations considered procedural or sequential blocks? If so, should I be declaring the top module's output ports as output reg's since the instantiations kind of act like always blocks with specific sensitivity lists?

Answer (score 0):

The Verilog language itself does not force You to define outputs solely as output reg's, if there is combinational relation required between downstream and upstream module then it is perfectly fine to declare such outputs without reg modifier. However there are some good practice guidelines, for instance it this is top level module and output is considered as Primary Output (most likely will interface with some sort of I/O) then it is recommended to ensure that such output is of registered type but again language does not prevent You from doing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

These simple rules apply:

- if assigned in an `assign` statement or driven by the output or inout of an instance, then it must be a wire;
- if assigned by an `initial` or `always` block, then it must be a variable.

But then you knew that already and this question has been asked many times. What makes yours different is what about the situation where something is initially driven by an `initial` or `always` block, but is then an output of an instance. The answer is: **it is an output of an instance and so must be a wire. How it is driven inside the instance is not relevant.** See this line here:

```
.this_must_be_a_variable(so_must_this_be_a_wire)
```

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5kmV

```
module TOP (input      verilog_inputs_are_always_wires, 
            output     this_must_be_a_wire, 
                       so_must_this_be_a_wire, 
            output reg this_must_be_a_variable);

  BOT b ( 
    .verilog_inputs_are_always_wires(verilog_inputs_are_always_wires), 
    .this_must_be_a_wire(this_must_be_a_wire), 
    .this_must_be_a_variable(so_must_this_be_a_wire)
  );

endmodule

module BOT (input      verilog_inputs_are_always_wires, 
            output     this_must_be_a_wire, 
            output reg this_must_be_a_variable);

  assign this_must_be_a_wire = verilog_inputs_are_always_wires;

  always @(*) this_must_be_a_variable = verilog_inputs_are_always_wires;

endmodule
```